# React public folder usage - when to use it and how does it work?

Tags: reactjs

I haven't been able to find enough information on how the public folder in React works in terms of end user accessing it.

Does the `public` folder get downloaded for the end user once they access the main site (link with no slashes to a file in public folder like `/public/my_file.txt`, but instead the usual `/`)?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is, it seems to be about the different things. Your public folder doesn't get copied by react if that's what you're asking but...

Comment: Hey, I've removed the other information as it's not relevant to the question. Your comment answers my question.